# Restrict user to enter numeric value with 2 place decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a code which restricts the user to enter numeric value with decimal up to 2 place.
The script below is working but code is not allowing users to use backspace or delete key or navigation key like (left, right, up, down). I also want users not to be able to enter 0 or more than 70 as value. So users can enter min value 1 or max 70 or 65.21 etc.

Just guide me what to change in this code.

```
$('.number').keypress(function (event) {
    if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    var text = $(this).val();

    if ((text.indexOf('.') != -1) && (text.substring(text.indexOf('.')).length > 2)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

I got a jquery based a library which works like a charm but the library requires a higher version of jquery but our company using jquery version 1.4.1 (jquery-1.4.1.min.js)

The below script and guide me on how to develop one which will work smoothly with jquery version 1.4.1.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <!-- jQuery and Plugin References -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/autoNumeric-1.9.18.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function($) {
      // Only allow integer values with a max of 70 (denoted by the vMax parameter)
      $('.numericOnly').autoNumeric('init', { vMax: 70, lZero: 'deny', aSep: '', mDec: 0 });    
    });  
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Define your specific properties for your field -->
  <input type="text" class="numericOnly" >
</body>
```

[working sample](http://jsbin.com/fajedi/1/edit?html,output)

looking for guidance.thanks

### EDIT

i just update a small area like min value can not be 0 rather it should be 1.

```
$('.numericOnly').keyup(function (event) {
    var text = $(this).val();
    console.log(text);
    var hasToBeSet = false;
    if ( text.length === 1 && text[0] === '.' ){
        hasToBeSet = true;
        text = "";    
    }
    else if ((text.match(/\./g) || []).length === 2) {
        hasToBeSet = true;
        text = text.substring(0,text.length - 1);
    } else if (text === "70.") {
        hasToBeSet = true;
        text = "70";
    } else if (parseFloat(text) > 70) {
        hasToBeSet = true;
        text = "70";
    } else if (parseFloat(text) < 1) {
        text = "1";
        hasToBeSet = true;
    } else if (text.indexOf(".") !== -1 && text.substring(text.indexOf(".") + 1, text.length).length >= 3) {
        hasToBeSet = true;
        text = text.substring(0, text.indexOf(".")) + text.split('').splice(text.indexOf("."), 3).join('')
    }
    if (hasToBeSet) $(this).val(text);
}).keypress(function (event) {
    console.log(event.keyCode);
    if ((event.which != 46 && event.keyCode != 8 && event.keyCode != 16 && !(event.keyCode >= 37 && event.keyCode <= 40) && event.which != 0) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});

<input type="text" class="numericOnly" onpaste="return false">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a possible solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/2dnvpn52/17/

I added two things:
-onpaste return false (in order to prevent some code paste into the input)
-changed the event to keyup in order to have the actual value (keypress is faster, so you aren't getting the true value of the input)

This was the logic applied:

```
//Checking if is more than 70 or less than 70
if (parseFloat(text) > 70) {
    text = "70";
    hasToBeSet = true;
} else if (text < 0){
    hasToBeSet = true;
    text = "0";
}
else if (text.indexOf(".") !== -1 && text.substring(text.indexOf(".") + 1, text.length).length >= 3) {
//Checking if it has a dot and then getting the part after the ., and check if it is longer than 2
    text = text.substring(0, text.indexOf(".")) + text.split('').splice(text.indexOf("."), 3).join('');
    hasToBeSet = true;
}
if ( hasToBeSet )
   $(this).val(text);
```

**EDIT**: I change the code and the jsfiddle putting the event.which on keypress event

Comment: i want user can not enter 0. the min value will be 1 and max will 70.i saw when i put 1 and press backspace then 1 is not getting deleted. i guess backspace key press is blocked. backspace,delkey and navigation key,shift key should not be blocked. if possible please check and rectify the code. thanks

Comment: Can you enter 0.dd? Because if you can, the check has to be set into the validation thing.
I changed the code so that navigation keys should work, but, in which browsers are you experiencing the backspace issue? BTW I added to the not blocked keys: backspace, delete and shift

Comment: i am testing in firefox.

Comment: sorry still js fiddle js is not working. not taking backspace.

Comment: Can you try again with the new one? Eventually, which keyboard layout are you using and which version of FF

Comment: i forgot to mention that still there is one issue. now textbox allowing to enter 70.1 but i said our max value can not be more than 70. will you look into this. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simple way is to check number of Decimal places on each keypress. Following is stub for same,

```
Private Sub Text1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    If KeyAscii = 46 Then
        If InStr(Text1.Text, ".") > 1 Then
            KeyAscii = 0
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This will restrict user from entering two or more decimal places. Now add your logic to prevent user from entering Decimal Places at the start and end of the input string.

Comment: here i am asking about web & javascript not winapps.